# Java executes 'catch' block with no error, and somehow still runs 'try' block

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with the following code. First, I am a newbie to Java with experience with several other languages.

When I run the following on Android, it errors at "in.close();", jumps to the catch block and runs Return ""; The thing is, the function doesn't return an empty string, it successfully returns the correct json data even though the debugger says it isn't running return json, but that it's running return "";

```
public void fetch() {

    // Get the JSON of the image gallery
    String json = getJSON();

    // json somehow has the actual correct json data and not an empty string!

};

private String getJSON() {

    try {
        // Create a URL for the desired page
        URL url = new URL("http://imgur.com/gallery.json");

        // Read all the text returned by the server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String json = in.readLine();
        in.close();
        return json; // <-- debugger doesn't break here!
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("getJSON", e.getMessage());
        return ""; // <-- debugger breaks here! Cat Log shows nothing!
    }
}
```

I copy the exact same code into a Java console so that I can output the error message and watch it in the debugger with break points, and the code executes without error.

```
    try {
        // Create a URL for the desired page
        URL url = new URL("http://imgur.com/gallery.json");

        // Read all the text returned by the server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String json = in.readLine();
        in.close();
        System.out.println(json);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

What exactly is going on? Why is my code run on Android erroring when it runs in a Java Console just fine? Why when it errors does it not return what the error is supposed to return; and empty string? How can I view the error message in Android?

Comment: have you set Internet permission in manifest file ?

Comment: Are you sure you get an error? You can call `e.printStackTrace()` on your exception to get the exact type of exception and on what line it occured. This works for both regular java and Android (on android it shows up in the LogCat).

Comment: I added e.printStackTrace() in my catch block before the return, and nothing is showing up in my LogCat. If the function is returning the json correctly, and no error is being output, why then does the debugger break at the breakpoint on my return in the catch block?

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure to include the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

permission in your `androidManifext.xml`.

You are trying to retrieve data from a remote location. 
On Java console you can do it without such permissions, but not in Android.

Comment: It is included, and successfully returns the json data in Android, but it jumped to the catch block and runs return "", but the function actually still somehow returns the json data and not an empty string.

Comment: You should clean up your project and try again. Android debugger does sometimes such strange things.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about "System.out.println" in Android.
You can use "Logcat" view in Eclipse. This is used to show every log you want from your device.
Also, you can replace "`System.out.println(json);`" by "`Log.e("MyApp", "Here is my Json: '"+json+"'");`" and you'll see your json in the logcat... ;)

About your exception, you have a method in the frameworkthat automatically logs the exceptions in the logcat: "`myException.printStackTrace();`"

Comment: There is another one Log.e() method: [Log.e(String, String, Throwable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#e%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29). It can be used for logging exceptions too.

Comment: Nothing is appearing in my LogCat with any of those when I use it in the catch block before the return, even though the debugger breaks on the return. The only thing in my LogCat (which sits in it) is:   ?:??: W/?(?): Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory

Comment: Do you have a device connected? Or even the emulator? Then go in the "DDMS perspective", click on it in the list, then "Window/Show View/Log Cat"...

Comment: I am using my phone which I have connected. Log Cat is visible in the Debug tab as well as the DDMS tab. Nothing appears in the Log Cat. I am using:      catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e("getJSON", e.getMessage());
      return "";
     }

Comment: Did you try to put a break point in the catch clause and run your project in debug mode? It's the best way to know what's happening...

Answer (score 0):

A Reader reads text, an InputStream binary data. The bridge InputStreamReader needs a character encoding, and takes in your case the default OS encoding.

So better explicitly use an encoding:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

As JSON should better be in UTF-8, I have given that. But the default encoding on Android is UTF-8 and with you probably Cp1252. So there might be something else wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be correct.  If you did see a JSON returned, then you were not getting any `IOException` from `close`.

**Edit**:

Your updated source code clearly shows that there is no return from `finally` or retry logic in play here.  Good.

Visit the following setting in your environment: Window / Preferences / Run/Debug / Launching / "Launch in debug mode when workspace contains breakpoints"

Set this to *Always* or *Prompt*.  (If it was previously *Never*, you might 
have been running in Run mode, thus employing optimizations you did not want.  The two return statements may have been combined into one by the optimizer.)  After you change this setting, you should never see a breakpoint hit at a line different from the line on which it was set.  Please double check your findings with the new setting.

There is also an alternate way of breaking on exceptions (Suspend On Caught Exceptions) that is immune to this kind of optimization, if for any reason you do not want to run in debug mode.

Comment: Even if I only have a breakpoint placed on the return "" in the catch block, it still breaks on the catch block. There is no breakpoint in the try block.

Comment: @Fase - In that case I can promise you that the empty string gets returned.  However, there may be another catch block down the stack that manages to retry.

Comment: The empty string is NOT returned. The json from the URL is returned. I can see the json in the debugger, and the program moves on an loads images from the json. It can guarantee you json is returned.

Comment: @Fase - I trust your report but Java doesn't do this.  Once an exception is thrown, the try block's return statement will never execute.  The only thing that can trump the `return` in your `catch` block, is a `return` in a subsequent `finally` block.   It may help if you add more context (calling code) if you have it, to the question.

Comment: I understand that this is not supposed to be possible, as my experience with every other language. This is why I am left baffled. I guess I would have to upload some images to prove it?

Comment: @Fase, no, I have no doubt, but uploading more surrounding code would help.

Comment: Here is proof: http://imgur.com/a/pNyw2 (The hoster automatically shrunk my images)

Comment: I uploaded the original post with the code you see in the images.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11244/discussion-between-jirka-hanika-and-fase)